# .Net Forms Authentication Issue - 401, even though cookie set

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, iis

I'm new to C Sharp, Windows Forms Authentication, IIS....pretty much everything.

My issue:

-I'm validating the login/password credentials in a boolean method

-Upon true, I run the following:

```
//set and pass auth cookie
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, myUser, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), isPersistent, String.Empty, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedCookie);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(myUser,true);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(myUser,isPersistent);
```

The cookie is being set from what I can see in firebug.  However, when I redirect to the specified page above, I'm given a 401 - Unauthorized notification.  Is this being caused by an error in my code or perhaps, because the user/pass is being authenticated outside of the Windows domain?  Am I supposed to decrypt the ticket on the secure page - something I thought done by IIS/.Net?

Included is my Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms"> 
          <forms defaultUrl="Secure/km.html" loginUrl="Public/login.html" name=".ASPXAUTH" requireSSL="true"> 
          </forms>
        </authentication>
   </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but I've gone through them and cannot seem to figure it out.  Any help would be welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I had the files named .html.  After going back through the tutorials one more time, I renamed everything to .aspx and low and behold it worked as intended.

Thanks for the tips guys and hope this helps someone else.

This is my final code

```
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
    this.myUser,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
    this.isPersistent,
    String.Empty,  //Before I had this, Response.Redirect would return to Login
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    // Encrypt the ticket.
    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Create the Cookie
    HttpCookie myCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(this.myUser, this.isPersistent);

   if(this.isPersistent)
      myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
   else
      myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

   myCookie.HttpOnly = true;
   myCookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
   Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
   Response.Redirect("/Secure/km.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

have you implemented code in your global.asax.cs `Application_AuthenticateRequest` or `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` to get the `FormsIdentity` and convert it to an `IPrincipal` on `HttpContext.Current.User`?

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;
        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;

        var formsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;          
        var roles = formsIdentity.Ticket.UserData.Split(',');
        var gp = new GenericPrincipal(formsIdentity, roles);
        HttpContext.Current.User = gp;
    }
```

Require authorization in your web.config\system.web.

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Comment: First off, thank you for your reply.  No I haven't.  This goes in global.asax.cs - how does global.asax inherit it?  Is this automatically called for every webpage?  It looks exactly like what I need, but I've left campus and cannot check until the morning.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I now have that in my global.asax.cs but it hasn't affected anything from what I see.  Is this supposed to be called at some level?  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  What is the actual global.asax file supposed to look like?

Comment: To force that to be called, the application will need to require authentication.  There is a good starter article over at [msdn]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.90).aspx .